# Excluding a maven dependency that doesn't resolve

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to maven so bear with. It appears a dependency of an external dependency no longer resolves and build fails. I can't make changes even to the internal project so needs to be a local fix. What is the best way to get around this? Something in .m2/settings.xml?

```
[INFO] Building <internal-project>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://m2.modularity.net.au/snapshots/net/modularity/modularity-parent/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata net.modularity:modularity-parent:1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to modularity-snapshots (http://m2.modularity.net.au/snapshots): m2.modularity.net.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Downloading: http://m2.modularity.net.au/snapshots/net/modularity/modularity-parent/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/modularity-parent-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] <internal-project> ................................... SUCCESS [  1.274 s]
[INFO] <internal-project> ............................... FAILURE [  0.665 s]
[INFO] <internal-project> ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.104 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-04T15:12:27+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <internal-project>: Could not resolve dependencies for project <internal-project>: Failed to collect dependencies at <internal-project> -> <internal-project> -> <internal-project> -> org.semanticdesktop.aperture:aperture-core:jar:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT -> net.fortuna.mstor:mstor:jar:0.9.13-20100823122854: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.fortuna.mstor:mstor:jar:0.9.13-20100823122854: Could not transfer artifact net.modularity:modularity-parent:pom:1.0.8-SNAPSHOT from/to modularity-snapshots (http://m2.modularity.net.au/snapshots): m2.modularity.net.au: Unknown host m2.modularity.net.au -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The servername can not be resolved....

Comment: If you have the jar you can install it directly into your local .m2 folder so maven doesn't need to download it

Comment: Will have to see if I can find it. If I can't, is there a way to exclude a dependency? I don't think it's actually used in the local project.

Comment: what is your dependency, were you able to locate that from your repositories that you have listed in settings.xml or your pom.xml

Comment: @kbird looks like aperture... <internal-project> -> org.semanticdesktop.aperture:aperture-core:jar:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT -> net.fortuna.mstor:mstor:jar:0.9.13-20100823122854: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.fortuna.mstor:mstor:jar:0.9.13-20100823122854: Could not transfer artifact net.modularity:modularity-parent:pom:1.0.8-SNAPSHOT from/to modularity-snapshots (http://m2.modularity.net.au/snapshots): m2.modularity.net.au: Unknown host m2.modularity.net.au -> [Help 1]

Comment: I'd like to see if it builds with net.modularity:modularity-parent:pom:1.0.8-SNAPSHOT excluded somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > If you have the jar you can install it directly into your local .m2 folder so maven doesn't need to download it –  Alessandro Da Rugna

I went with this in the end. Thanks Alessandro and others!